# Change the number of taskbar thumbnails to show before the become s stacked list in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I am trying to change the number of  taskbar thumbnails to show before they become a stacked list in windows 10.

I have a 1920X1080 screen so the limit was 16. I created and modified the regedit key "NumThumbnails" and it worked until 19 thumbnails instead of 16 and then it became again a stacked list.

Comment: 19 is already more than most people have found as their limit...

Comment: thank you for your answer but as i said i need more than 19,this proves that the regedit worked but there is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "something else" is a hard coded limit based on some other factor that we do not have access to.

Evidence indicates this is not some wide open configuration: You have a limited number of values you CAN set, and then you are constrained by something you CANNOT set. In your case you've already found the upper limit on your computer.